# 'Shutting down: Master' in Google Cloud Run application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We have a Google Cloud run application that runs at 1am every morning to ingest, process, and output some data files. Currently, we have max concurrency, as timing is important.

Over the past weeks we have noticed several errors generated by the platform.

The Cloud Run logs themselves show `Shutting down: Master`

At a similar timestamp, a logging sink picks up

```
The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.
```

We have modified the instances and concurrency, as well as memory and vCPUs available, and they just show the same error but generated over a longer period of time.

There are no other errors or logs generated to give us any further info.

Any ideas where we may be going wrong?

Edit:
The full trace from the Cloud Run log is below

```
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[4] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4
[5] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5
[6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
[1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[6] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6)
[5] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5)
[4] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4)
[1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Comment: Can you share the log trace of the shutting down master? And can you specify the region where you saw this?

Comment: Your container is not processing requests so it is being shutdown (sigterm). I think you are confusing max concurrency with minimum number of instances. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances

Answer (score 0):

My situation was the same.
I sloved it by stop the firewall.

Comment: How do you stop the firewall